# Why do I see different outputs in this code when comparing debugging and running without the debugger attached?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, event-loop

```html
<button id="BTN" type="button">Click Me</button>
<p id="p-text"></p>
<p id="p-result"></p>
<script>
    document.getElementById("BTN").addEventListener('click', function () {
        document.getElementById("p-text").innerText = "Calculating...."    // breakpoint set here
        foo();
        // setTimeout(foo, 0); 
    })
    foo = function () {
        let result = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            for (let j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
                for (let k = 0; k < 1000; k++) {
                    result = result + i + j + k;
                }
            }
        }
        document.getElementById("p-text").innerText = "Calculate Done"
        document.getElementById("p-result").innerText = result.toString()
    }
</script>
```

I knew when button clicked on page above should replace the "Calculating..." to "Calaulate Done" and insert the result of the foo function into the p-result tag! And that page above should never show the "Calculating..." cause Event Queue's order.

The Question is: Why, when I use the debugger in Chrome, it shows me "Calculating..." on the page while the **foo function not end yet?**

It will show this
[image]

Comment: what is the issue? on click calculating is not showing btw.

Comment: I update the image description! XD

Comment: it'll show `calculating...` because the above line is executed.

Comment: Shouldn't  it will put the `Calculating...` render event callback after the cilck event callback?

Comment: @Liam when running the code, the UI tread is blocked from making the first update and showing "Calculating..." but when stepping through with a debugger, it exhibits a different behaviour and shows "Calculating...". That discrepancy is what OP is asking about.

Comment: That makes more sense

Comment: @VLAZ Yes!!!!!!!  That's what question i want to show!!!  Thanks!!

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't really have a good explanation for you other than "that's just how it works". FF also exhibits the same behaviour and I'd imagine the other browsers would, too. It's a difference to "normal" running but...hardly matters the vast majority of time. Dunno if it's intentional or just happens to work that way for a different reason. At the very least, it's a useful thing when debugging, so you know you actually targetted the same element even though normally you don't see any change. Again, though - this might be a side-effect, not goal when implementing the debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the `debugger` keyword or breakpoints will only block the JavaScript execution; the event loop will actually not be blocked entirely.
There is a note in the ["pause"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#pause) part of the event loop which asks the User Agent (UA) to not follow the specs and instead to choose a way to pause the JS execution while keeping the rendering alive, like the enter the ["spin the event loop"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#spin-the-event-loop) algorithm does. This state can be reached in various circumstances, all are not defined in the specs, and all are not standards (i.e all UAs don't do it).

One that is defined is when deferred scripts [are being fetched](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#the-end). One that is not standard is all user prompts like `alert()`, where Firefox will keep updating the rendering but Chrome won't.

`debugger` or breakpoints are not part of the HTML specs (which do specify the event loop's behavior), and I don't know if all browsers that do support it behave the same, but it seems major vendors actually do.

Note that both examples here are not really using the "spin the event loop" algorithm, since they won't execute a microtask checkpoint where the *true* algorithm would.